# Javascript following window.print(); not running in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing, onclick

I am attempting to print a form before it is submitted by a submit input control. 
My code is

```
<input type="submit" name="printForm" 
       value="Print Application Form"
       onClick="window.print(); 
       if (submitting) {return false;}
       else {submitting = true; return true;} ">

('submitting' a global 'var', initialised as 'false' - to stop double sends)
```

This works in Safari, Chrome and IE, but is giving a problem in Firefox - the form is not submitted after the printing completes - however, if the print dialog in Firefox is cancelled, the form is submitted.

I have tried moving the window.print into a function to isolate it. but that didn't change the result.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks

I have searched here for anything related to window.print and scanned many questions without finding anything that helped. (I haven't read all of the thousands yet!)

Comment: Shouldn't `window.print()` be in the else block? Anyhow, the submit listener should be on the form, not the button as forms can be submitted without pressing the button.

Comment: No, I don't mind if the user wants to print the form multiple times, but I don't want it submitted multiple times. If I move the onclick code to the form onsubmit, the form is sent, but the window is not printed.

Comment: Oppps - rushed that test too much. Corrected, and result is no different from having the code in the <input onclick>  ... See answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer ... in the original problem, the javascript was all being executed, but something in the window.print inhibited the actual send of the form.

The solution is to change the  to button, and move the actual form submit into javascript, and position the submit to occur immediately before the window.print (instead of after!). In this way, both the form submit and the page print actually occur.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be in the form action. `<form action="">`
If you are loading a file on form submit then pass that file's complete path in the action instead of relative path.

Comment: I have changed the <form> as suggested above to

`<form action="ballotappl.php" method="POST" name="SendForm" 
            onsubmit="window.print(); if (submitting) {return false;}
                                 else {submitting = true; return true;} " />`

but this makes no difference